# Google Sheet formula on showing the lowest number if none of the values equals 0 does not work

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to create a formula that meets the following conditions:

- If any of the cells is 0, then just show 0
- If none of the cells equals 0, then show the lowest number of those cells

So let's say A1 has a value of 2; A5 is 3 and A13 is 0, then I want the formula to show "0".
On the other hand, if A1 is 2, A5 is 3 and A13 is 1, I want the formula to show "1".

I think the solution relies on conditional formatting and mincounts, but couldn't find a formula that works.
Please keep in mind that I don't want the values to be summed, only to show the lowest value.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this formula will solve your problem:

<strike>=If(A1:A<>0,min(A1:A),0)</strike>

```
min(A1:A)
```

p.s.: I don't understand why you brought up conditional formatting, but if instead you wanted to highlight the zero or the minimum of the various values ​​respectively, then you could apply this custom formula to the conditional formatting of the range **A1:A**

<strike>=and(A1<>"",A1=If(A1<>0,min($A$1:$A),0))</strike>

```
=and(A1<>"",A1=min($A$1:$A))
```

Comment: Neither of these formulas will work correctly because the `if()` will only evaluate `A1` and ignore the rest of column `A`.

Comment: you are right, I stand corrected

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The `min()` function automatically skips blank cells and text strings. Assuming that no number is negative, you can simply use this:

`=min(A1:A)`

Comment: Thanks, this worked, this was much simpler than I thought.